# Usage of preposition "on" followed by "homework" and preceded by "problem"

Tags: prepositions

Is it Ok to use "on" in the following sentence:

> *There are some problems **on** the homework I didn't get.*

Or I should use another preposition?

Comment: Here "Problems" should be followed by proposition "with".

Comment: And I think it is better to say "There were some problems with the homework I didn't get." Or  " There are some problems with the homework I don't get."

Comment: "On" is acceptable, "with" is better.  And "I didn't get" seems to imply that you did not receive the problems.  If you meant you did not understand then "I don't get" is more idiomatic, though probably a rephrasing would be more appropriate.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "problems." If the homework consists of 10 problems to solve, then "in" or "on" are probably best.  If the homework itself is problematic, then "with" is best. And your vague use of "get" (receive? complete? understand?) complicates this further.

Comment: @haha Your opinion about the acceptability of 'on' here differs from that of Mudly. Google Ngrams and raw Google data indicate strongly that Mudly is correct. The 'surface metaphor' is often used with 'on the homework', as with 'on the list' and 'on the agenda'.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common colloquialism to reference things either on, in, or with one's homework. It's acceptable to use "on" in this situation, as saying there was "a problem *with* the homework" could take on meaning that there was a clerical error, a typo, a factual error, etc., within the requirements of the homework.

That said, your sentence has an unrelated problem -- it can mean two very different things. Did you not understand the problems? Or did you not receive the homework? You could change "get" to "receive" or "understand" to clear up any ambiguity.

Better, you could restate the sentence as "I did not understand some of the problems on the homework."